# example ipv6 netmask that is not in prefix length form

Tags: ipv6, netmask

`FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329/128` is an IPv6 address with netmask.

For IPv4, the netmask could be given as `/24` or `255.255.255.0`, either format.

How can I represent `/128` that is not a prefix length ?
Like, `255.255.255.0` is not a prefix length.

One way to verify is to use this site:

https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv6CIDRToRangeResult?ipAddress=FE80%3A0000%3A0000%3A0000%3A0202%3AB3FF%3AFE1E%3A8329%2F128

It should not give error.

Comment: IPv6 notation is _always_ CIDR notation, not with a mask.

Comment: @RonMaupin: An IPv6 address is not *always* expressed in CIDR notation, it depends on the context.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, from [RFC 4941, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture, Section 2.3. Text Representation of Address Prefixes](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.3): "_The text representation of IPv6 address prefixes is similar to the way IPv4 address prefixes are written in Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR) notation [CIDR].  An IPv6 address prefix is represented by the notation:_ `ipv6-address/prefix-length`"

Comment: @RonMaupin: that says "*An IPv6 address **prefix** is represented by ...*", it does not say "*An IPv6 address is represented by ...*".  An IPv6 address **itself** is not required to be represented in CIDR notation, only when its **prefix** needs to be expressed.  Most users of IP addresses don't use prefixes directly.  Network admins do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I didn't say an IPv4 _address_ uses CIDR notation. The RFCs are clear that the `address mask` notation, common to IPv4, is not used for IPv6, and it has been replaced with CIDR notation. Any text representation that includes a mask instead of the prefix length is non-standard.

Comment: @RonMaupin: you said "*IPv6 notation is always CIDR notation*", which is not always true. An IPv6 address can be (and usually is) in IPv6 notation without being in fully CIDR notation. Just saying.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, what I wrote was in the context of the question, which was asking how to use a mask instead of a prefix length. IPv6 notation doesn't do that. Mask notation doesn't apply to IPv6, it is always CIDR notation.

Comment: @RonMaupin: OK, granted. Then I must have misread what you wrote. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

`/#` notation simply means the first `#` bits of an IP address represent something, and the remaining bits represent something else.

In IPv4, `/24` means the first 24 bits represent a subnet and the last 8 bits represent a host within the subnet.  When used by itself to express a subnet mask, `/24` looks like these bits:

```
    11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000
```

Which is `255.255.255.0` in dotted notation.  If you apply `/24` to an actual IPv4 address, for example `192.168.0.1`, you get these bits:

```
    192.168.0.1    = 11000000 10101000 00000000 000000001
    AND /24        = 11111111 11111111 11111111 000000000
    -----------------------------------------------------
    subnet         = 11000000 10101000 00000000|000000000 (192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255)
    host in subnet = 00000000 00000000 00000000|000000001 (1)
```

`/#` works similarly in IPv6.  The first `#` bits of an IPv6 address represent the routing prefix.  An IPv6 address is 128 bits in size, so `/128` by itself is `FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF`, and `/24` is `FFFF:FF00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000` (which can also be expressed in a shortened format as `FFFF:FF00::`).

When `/128`is applied to an IPv6 address, like `FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329`, the routing prefix is the full IP address, thus the IP represents a specific machine with no subnets (`No. of Host: 1` in your test website).  Applying `/24` on the same IPv6 address would have a routing prefix of `FE80:0000::` instead, which leaves 104 bits open for subnetting.  See [IPv6 Subnetting - Overview and Case Study](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/66991/ipv6-subnetting-overview-and-case-study).

Comment: When I gave FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329/FFFF:FF00:: to the test site, it says "The mask length for the IPv6 address is invalid." From the discussion above, I conclude that the test site is reporting correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @labrat43: As Ron stated, unlike IPv4, IPv6 prefixes are *never* expressed in `/FFFF:FF00::` noation, only in `/24` notation.